# Ncurses/C/C++: Program sometimes skips input, printing, or both

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

For some reason this Ncurses code (see below) is sometimes not stopping to get input (with getnstr()), stoping to print (with printw()), or doing either. (Ncurses code begins at int main(). I've included the entire program for completeness sake. It's my first 'big' project)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ncurses.h>
//name that will be avaliable to everything
std::string pubName;
//const which is the number of items
static const int numberOfItems = 5;
//Array with the 'human' names for items to help when displaying the items
static const std::string humanNames[numberOfItems] = {"Empty", "A Wooden Sword", "A Bronze Sword", "An Iron Sword", "A Steel Sword"};
//stores enums will values 0-6 with 0 meaning that the inventory has nothing in that slot and 1-6 being items;
enum item{NOITEM = 0, SWORDWD = 1, SWORDBRZ = 2, SWORDIRN = 3, SWORDSTL = 4, SWORDSCIMITAR = 5, DAGGER = 6};
class Player{
    private:
        //stores name of user
        std::string name;
        //stores 6 enums which are the current items which the user has. Default state is no items.
        int inventory[6];
        //variable to prevent the use of an empty slot. When item is added or removed it increments or decrements respectivly
        int numOfItems;
        //stores health data for each slot so that potions can't be used more than once and other such things
        int invUseData[6];
        //stores health data for player
        int pHealth;
        //prevents the incrementing of health above acceptable levels and allows for health ups (Give you more hearts).
        int curMaxHealth;
    public:
        //sets default values
        Player(std::string newName){
            for (int n=0; n<6; n++) {
                inventory[n] = NOITEM;
            }
            //sets name 
            name = newName;
            //sets health to default 100
            pHealth = 100;
            //sets item count to 0
            numOfItems = 0;
            //set maxhealth to default 100.
            curMaxHealth = 100;
        }
        //adds attempts to add item to inventory. If inventory is full it returns false if when inventory is full
        bool addItToInv(item ){
            //TODO
            return false;
        }
        //negates one health point of an item. Returns false if health of slot is 0
        bool useItem( int slot){
            //TODO
            return false;
        }
        //returns health of player
        int returnHealth(){
            return pHealth;
        }
        //returns name of player
        std::string returnName(){
            return name;
        }
        //returns name of item in slot
        std::string returnNameOfSlot(int slotNum){
            return humanNames[inventory[slotNum]];
        }
};
//class for monster
class Monster{
    private:
        int health;
};
//Does all the things needed at the end of turn (I.E.: Checks health)
void onEndTurn(){
    //TODO
}
int main(){
    //sets up memory for a temporary name
    char* nameTemp = new char[20];
    initscr();
    getnstr(nameTemp, 19);
    clear();
    move(1,0);
    Player pOne(nameTemp);
    std::string pubName = pOne.returnName();
    delete nameTemp;
    refresh();
    printw(pubName.c_str());
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Just ask if you  need more details about my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only thing I can guess would be causing this is an extra newline in the input buffer. Perhaps before the calls to `getnstr()` and `printw()` try calling `flushinp()`. This should be in ncurses... More info at  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcurses/flushinp.html

Comment: @jonhopkins It didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Dang.. Most times I see a C++ question where some input or output isn't working, that's almost always the answer. That's all I can think of at the moment, so I hope someone more familiar with ncurses comes by and can figure it out... I'll see if I can get around to testing this out though.